# How to take user input, pass it to a function as a string, and renders the function result on the screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have managed to add an input field to my webpage, but have no idea how to get that input, pass into a function as a string and render the result to my webpage.

Below is my code, followed by the function that I want to have the user input passed into.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './caesar.png';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
    <div className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h2>Caesar's Cipher (Rot-13), built with React. See the code</h2>
    </div>
    <p className="App-intro">
      The Caesar Shift is a famous encryption technique used by Julius Caesar around 100 years BC.
    </p>
    <p className="App-intro">
      It consists of taking in a message and shifting all of its letters by 13 numbers in the alphabet.
    </p>
    <p className="App-intro">
      In the example below, A will become N, the 13th letter in the alphabet:
    </p>
    <h1 className="App-background">
      "A" --> "N"
    </h1>
    <p className="App-intro">
      The same can be done with whole words and sentences:
    </p>
    <h1 className="App-background">
      "Attack Friday midnight" --> "Nggnpx Sevqnl zvqavtug"
    </h1>
    <div class="ui input"><input type="text" placeholder="Encrypt something!" /></div>
  </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;

// function I want to have the input passed to.

let alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');

const caesar = input => {
  let splitName = input.toLowerCase().split(''), convertedString = [], newLetter;

  for (i = 0; i < splitName.length; i++) {
if (splitName[i] === ' ') {
  convertedString.push(splitName[i])
}
for (j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
  if (splitName[i] === alphabet[j]) {
    newLetter = alphabet[j + 13];

    if (newLetter === undefined) {
      newLetter = alphabet[j - 13];
    }
    convertedString.push(newLetter);
  }
}
  } console.log(convertedString.join(''))
}
caesar(input)
```

I couldn't find any similar posts regarding this issue

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './caesar.png';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
     result: ''
  }
  caesar = e => { 
    // get input with e.target.value
    const result = // apply your function to input
    this.setState({ result })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
    <div className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h2>Caesar's Cipher (Rot-13), built with React. See the code</h2>
    </div>
    <p className="App-intro">
      The Caesar Shift is a famous encryption technique used by Julius Caesar around 100 years BC.
    </p>
    <p className="App-intro">
      It consists of taking in a message and shifting all of its letters by 13 numbers in the alphabet.
    </p>
    <p className="App-intro">
      In the example below, A will become N, the 13th letter in the alphabet:
    </p>
    <h1 className="App-background">
      "A" --> "N"
    </h1>
    <p className="App-intro">
      The same can be done with whole words and sentences:
    </p>
    <h1 className="App-background">
      "Attack Friday midnight" --> "Nggnpx Sevqnl zvqavtug"
    </h1>
    <div class="ui input"><input onChange={this.caesar} type="text" placeholder="Encrypt something!" /></div>
     <div>{this.state.result}</div> // <-- Render result here
  </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks good, but I'd include a statement like this 
    `this.caesar = this.caesar.bind(this)`
in the constructor

Comment: That's correct @JeffHechler, thanks. I changed to arrow function, so you don't need to bind it.